# when using track to contraint to billboard sprites, how do i prevent them from being rotated?

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to do billboarded sprites that always face the camera, and for the most part it works, but i wish they were forced to to be straight up and down, not rotated at all (which happens near the sides). Is the possible with track to contraint?

[image]

here is my setup:

[image]

EDIT: with lemons suggestion

[image]

Comment: What's your setup? A copy rotation constraint would probably acheive this as you can pick which axes you want it to follow. Track constraints need more finessing as objects are orineted to the camera's origin rather that it's view plane.

Answer (score 1):

PS: it works if you want up down toward the Z axis... but the question was about up down along the screen...

Just add another constraint limiting their rotation.

[image]

Axis to be used depend on your objects initial orientations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: tried this and it's a little better, but still not perfectly straight (pic in top post)

Comment: @stackers, could you share a file with the issue you just shown.

Answer (score 1):

@callmepro had the right answer, copy rotation works much better than track to

[image]

Comment: ah... you meant up down on the screen... not up down on the Z axis... right?

Comment: yeah, sorry for the confusion

Comment: no problem, that's the game ;)